# Docker in docker : docker run hello-world error operation not permitted

Tags: docker

I got a message "docker: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: Error creating mount namespace before pivot: operation not permitted."
when i tried to run hello-world.

I cannot find what is wrong..

[step]

1. install docker desktop on windows10

- Docker version 20.10.12

2. docker run -it --privileged ubuntu:18.04
3. install docker on ubuntu:18.04

- Docker version 19.03.9

4. docker run hello-world

- docker: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: Error creating mount namespace before pivot: operation not permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are much easier ways to run docker commands inside a container:

- **using the docker UNIX socket or what people call docker on docker `DonD`:**

```bash
run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker ubuntu:20.04
```

once you run this you can try to run your docker commands it will work just fine but keep in mind!!

> this does the same thing as if you run the commands from your host machine

- **Run docker in docker or usually called `DinD`:**

```bash
docker run -d --privileged --name docker \
    -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs \
    -v docker-certs-ca:/certs/ca \
    -v docker-certs-client:/certs/client \
    docker:dind
```

then you can execute dond commands inside that container running:

```bash
docker exec -it dond sh
```

> This is a great alternative for you because it's lightweight and easy to setup!

You can find more [here](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/14890/how-and-why-to-run-docker-inside-docker/).

In case you insist to use the Ubuntu:18.04 and installing docker inside of it, I would first say you haven't specified how you installed docker it should probably work if you followed how to [install Docker on a Ubuntu machine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/), could be some volume mounting issue aswell, you can try to run these commands once the ubuntu container is created or just use a `Dockerfile`:

```bash
apt-get update &&\
apt-get install curl &&\
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add - &&\
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable" &&\
apt-cache policy docker-ce &&\
apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

and then running docker commands must work properly unless you have some network issues.